# ASP Net MVC calling function in controller from JS errors

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC project where I'm trying to call a method in my PunchesController called jobs. I've set a debugger on the method and it hits the jobs method and returns the correct results. I've even called the jobs method from Advanced Rest Client and it returns the correct results.

But in the jquery method I get "Uncaught TypeError: f.QueryResponseHeaders is not a function" which I cannot find much about through Google/stack overflow.

I've included the relevant code below:
[image: jobs method in PunchesController]

[image: Info from Advanced rest client]

[image: Updated JS]

json returned from Jobs method in PunchesController

```
[
{
  "Job":{
     "Id":"5932c49d-5f1b-443c-b43c-6107c832b07b",
     "Name":"Featured Actor"
  },
  "Status":0,
  "StartDate":"2015-08-12T00:00:00",
  "EndDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "PayRate":20000000.0,
  "Companies":[
     {
        "Id":"cb0e96a4-eaf2-4966-810f-7949581ba3fe",
        "Name":"Test Company"
     }
  ],
  "Id":"21aebb35-ade3-4cb3-83bb-db47824d1509",
}
]
```

I've tried adding an error handler to the GET call but it will never hit it. It always prints "Uncaught TypeError: f.QueryResponseHeaders is not a function" to the console and thats it. Any ideas?

Comment: show the code for loadjobs ,   it seems like it shoud look like loadjobs() , and should even accept at least one parameter , like loadjobs(data)

Comment: have you tried to delete `contentType` string from your ajax call?

Comment: Have you tried changing url end to var url = 'http://localhost:51345/punches/jobs/?id=' + employeeId ?

Comment: you use mvc or web api?

Comment: @teovankot I deleted everything except url, type, and success call back and it didn't fix it.

Comment: @ScottSelby I hastily changed to the .ajax call from a $.get call and did forget the params for loadjobs. I updated the JS in the original post.

Comment: @Nathan I changed the URL to 'localhost:51435/punches/jobs/' + employeeId; and got "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: @chenZ its an mvc controller not web api controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a hunch I downgraded my jquery version from 2.1.4 to 1.11.3 and it all works now. I'm not sure what was causing the error but it's at least fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `contentType` parameter?:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/punches/jobs/' + employeeId,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Also, you could use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
$.getJSON(url, params, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

As a side note, as of **jQuery v1.4**, the serialization of parameters has changed. You may need to set `traditional` to `true` if you need to support previous param serialization. More information on the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).
Set the property on each call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    traditional: true,
    ...
});
```

Or set it globally like this (this will apply to all further ajax calls):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    traditional:true
});
```

Comment: I tried this just now and it neither worked. I got the same error. On a hunch I downgraded my jquery version from 2.1.4 to 1.11.3 and it all works now.

Comment: @AndrewM strange thing, I'm using both approaches with jQuery v2.1.4, maybe your previous jquery js file was corrupted? Have you tried download it again?

Comment: I didn't try downloading 2.1.4 again. I'll have to try that later and report back.

Comment: @AndrewM, great let us know what happens... I also added more information to the answer that could be useful... good luck!